# How to select data to array field?

Tags: php, mysql, json

TableA:

```
idA: 1, name: John;
```

TableB:

```
idB: 1, product: milk, idA: 1;
idB: 2, product: egg, idA: 1;
```

And I want the finally JSON result look like that:

```
[
    {
        "idA": 1, 
        "name": "John", 
        "TableB": [
            {
                "idB": 1, 
                "product": "milk", 
                "idA": 1
            },
            {
                "idB": 2, 
                "product": "egg", 
                "idA": 1
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I'm using PHP and mySQL.
How's the query should be?
Thanks too much!
I'm so sorry because my English isn't well.

Comment: Where is your code? show us your effort.

Comment: I'm trying to use inner join but it's just give me multi row

Comment: It will, as you got 2 rows to pick from TableB for idA 1. Still can't see your query or code.

Comment: Hi. As ASR said: Please add your SQL code to the question. Were happy to help you debug and evolve your code but we wont write it from scratch for you.

Comment: Formatted result as _actual_ JSON

Comment: @NguyenQuocDat, I fear, you can't hydrate resulting set with relations in one go with just one request. At least, you need two separate request (to avoid [N+1 problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97197/what-is-select-n1)): one to fetch all needed data from first table (`select * form TableA as A where ...`), and then fetch all related data from TableB (`select * from TableB as B where B.idA in (<ids from TableA>) and ...`) and manually hydrate resulting set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Mysqli or pdo. Check the code below. I didn't test but it should work.

```
// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
  die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM TableA ORDER BY idA";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {

  $rows = array();
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $rows[] = $row;

    $sqlSub = "SELECT * FROM TableB WHERE idA = '{$row['idA']}' ORDER BY idB";  
    $resultSub = mysqli_query($conn, $resultSub);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($resultSub) > 0) {
        while ($rowSub = mysqli_fetch_array($resultSub)) {

            $rows[]['TableB'][] = $rowSub;
        }
    }

  }

  echo json_encode($rows);
} else {
  echo "no results found";
}
```

Comment: It's _exactly_ how N+1 problem looks like. Don't do like this.

Answer (score 0):

this query will returns to you a single row. I did not test it but it should work just fine.

```
select tA.idA,name, group_concat(idB) as cIdB,
 group_concat(product) as cProduct ,
 group_concat(tB.idA) as cIdA 
from Table A tA
left join Table B tB on tA.idA = tB.idA group by tB.idA
```

it should returns an array looks like this :

```
idA          1
name         Jhon
cIdB         1,2
cProduct     milk,egg
cIdA         1,1
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Get the rows from SQL with an inner join:

```
select TableA.*, TableB.* from TableA, TableB where TableA.idA = TableB.idA
```

Format the data in PHP:

```
$formattedResults = array(
"idA" => $result.idA, "name" =>  $result.name, "TableB" => array();
);
foreach ($results as $result) {
    $formattedResults["TableB"][] = array("idB"=> result.idB, "product"=> 
    result.product, "idA"=> result.idA;);
}

$json = json_encode($formattedResults);
```